# Is it possible to refresh AWS parameter store properties in Micronauts

Tags: micronaut

I have an app with a config class annotated with `@EachProperty` and a Factory method annotated with `@EachBean`. This works fine for properties that exist in the property sources at startup.

I am using the AWS parameter store config client to load the properties (just the default Micronauts parameter loading).

There will be the situation where new configs will be added at run time. I can add these to AWS parameter store but I am not sure how to get those new properties loaded and available for creating the beans from the factory method.

Is this something that is possible? Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mark the bean(s) that you want to refresh with the `@Refreshable` annotation and any time the application context gets refreshed, that bean will be refreshed, including receiving potentially updated config values.  One way the context gets refreshed is by way of invoking the `/refresh` endpoint, or it could be refreshed programatically.  See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0/guide/index.html#refreshable for more details on that.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this `applicationContext.publishEvent(new RefreshEvent())` but it didn't seem to force the AWS parameter store client to reload. Using `applicationContext.environment.refresh()` seemed to work but I fear that it's overkill...

Comment: The code behind the `/refresh` endpoint is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/9354b5607d181c2d4c8e36c431637cd31cb8b960/management/src/main/java/io/micronaut/management/endpoint/refresh/RefreshEndpoint.java#L59-L72.  That demonstrates one way to refresh diffs in an environment.